# React: If input value equals object key, then show key value

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

I have initialValue variable that holds input value and if user enters for example number 2, then I need to show text for this number 2 that is assigned in answers object, how can I do it?

I have got this far, but can't get further, maybe someone can help:

```
function App() {

  const [initialValue, setinitialValue] = useState(0);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([
    {
      1: "This is answer for number 1",
      2: "This is answer for number 2",
      3: "This is answer for number 3"
    }
  ]);

  const answerKeys = Object.keys(answers).forEach((key, i) => answers[key]);
  const answerValues = Object.values(answers).forEach((value) => value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <h1>What is your favorite number?</h1>
          <TextField id="filled-basic1" type="number" label="Add number" variant="filled" style={{margin:'10px'}} value={initialValue} onChange={e => setinitialValue(e.target.value)} />
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{margin:'20px 0'}} onClick={showAnswer}>Generate</Button>
          <hr style={{margin:'25px'}}/>
          <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <h2>Show value:</h2>
            <p>{initialValue === answerKeys ? answerValues : 'Something is wrong'}</p>
          </Container>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things that need to be corrected

- answers is an array of object whereas going by your logic it should have been an object
- forEach doesn't return anything
- you don't need arrays like answerKeys and answerValues if you maintain an object in state

You corrected code will look like

```
function App() {

  const [initialValue, setinitialValue] = useState(0);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState(
    {
      1: "This is answer for number 1",
      2: "This is answer for number 2",
      3: "This is answer for number 3"
    }
  );

  const showAnswer = () => {
      setShow(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <h1>What is your favorite number?</h1>
          <TextField id="filled-basic1" type="number" label="Add number" variant="filled" style={{margin:'10px'}} value={initialValue} onChange={e => setinitialValue(e.target.value)} />
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{margin:'20px 0'}} onClick={showAnswer}>Generate</Button>
          <hr style={{margin:'25px'}}/>
          {show && <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <h2>Show value:</h2>
            <p>{answers[initialValue]  ? answers[initialValue] : 'Something is wrong'}</p>
          </Container>}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Wonderful how easy you made this, thanks! Could you please advice me, is this approach for storing data in state variable good or there would be better to do different? Would I benefit in any way if I would store data in json file and import it in the component?

Comment: I would say, you can store the answers in an object outside of the class, since I don't see you changing it  anywhere. Apart from it the above solution should suffice

Comment: Ok, great. What approach I would need to take to show the answer only when hitting the button?

Comment: Updated answer for the required scenario